# How to automatically update the Service `spec.externalIPs` when a Kubernetes worker is drained/down?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm hosting a Kubernetes cluster on VMs/VPS from a random cloud provider not providing any Kubernetes things at all, meaning with a dedicated public IP address and to allow the trafic coming to the worker nodes, I'm defining my Service with the `spec.externalIPs` with the fixed list of IP addresses.

I'm looking for a way to get that list updated when a node is drained/down automatically.

I had a look at the existing operators from https://operatorhub.io/ but I haven't found any that seem to cover my use case.

The idea would that when the event of a node passing to NotReady is emitted, the Service is updated with the Nodes being Ready.

Is there any operator that could allow doing that?

Comment: What cloud provider do you use? Does this [help](https://github.com/doitintl/kubeip)

Comment: I'm not using GKE, I'm using VPS from a random cloud provider not providing any Kubernetes things at all, just VMs ;)

Answer (score 0):

After some time working on this, I finally figured out that this is not possible, at least today, there's no known operator or what so ever that could update the field with the IP addresses.

And even if it was the case, there would be delays to update the DNS records.

What I've done instead is to buy another VPS, installing HAproxy in order to proxy the Kubernetes API trafic to the master nodes, and the web trafic (both 80 and 443) to the Kubernetes worker nodes.

HAproxy monitors the nodes, and add/remove nodes automagically and in a very quick way.
With this, you just need one DNS record, pointing to the Load Balancer (or VIP of the Load Balancers in order to avoid SPOF), and HAproxy will do the rest!